# How to add a counter of a for loop and pass it across functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static

I am relatively new to programming. I have been working on a project that takes the users input passes it to a function that finds the factors of the number, stores them in an array (only for 100 factors max) and then returns the array to the main program. Once I call the array to the main program, then print it using a for loop i run into an issue. I need a counter to figure out the size of the array to figure out how many times to run the for loop.

So far I have tried to use a pointer to count the first loop and send it to the main function with no luck. The only thing that works is a global variable, but for obvious reasons I would prefer not to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int* get_factors(int number)
{
int x;
int z;
int y = 0;
static int arr[MAX_SIZE];

for(x=1; x <= number; ++x)
    {
        if (number%x == 0)
        {
        arr[y] = x;
        y++;
        }
    }
return arr;
}

int main(void)
{
int *num;
int temp;
int z = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&temp);

    printf("Factors of %d: ", temp);

    num = get_factors(temp);

    for(z=0; z<=20; z++) //This is the loop that i need to figure out a 
    counter for
    {
    printf("%d ", num[z]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this obvious reason not use a ”global” variable?

Comment: I've always been told that they can become confusing due to the fact that they can be accessed by any place in the code. And in smaller programs they won't cause many issues but in bigger programs I was told to avoid them.

Comment: that sounds right, and is your program a big one?

Comment: Why did you mangle your question so severely? Anyone can look at the history to see how it was before the mutilation

Comment: @Amadeus: if you see question vandalism, you are free to rollback without any further discussion (I've done that just now). It is very odd behaviour, but it is perhaps telling that the user has deleted their account (or been booted).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
struct myObject {
int arr[MAX_SIZE];
int index;
};

struct myObject
get_factors (int number)
{
int x;
struct myObject holder;
holder.index = 0;
for (x = 1; x <= number; ++x)
{
  if (number % x == 0)
{
  holder.arr[holder.index] = x;
  holder.index++;
}
}
return holder;
}

int
main (void)
{
struct myObject num;
int temp;
int z;
printf ("Enter a number: ");
scanf ("%d", &temp);

printf ("Factors of %d: ", temp);

num = get_factors (temp);

for (z = 0; z < num.index; z++) //This is the loop that i need to figure out a 
//counter for
{
  printf ("%d ", num.arr[z]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Used User Defined Datatype with the help of Struct and carried the index from get_factors method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I didn't even think of going about it like that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your function interface design, it could be easier to pass that information.

The idiomatic way to pass array in C function is via parameter, where the first paramenter is the array itself, and the second parameter is it maximun length.

In this way your function is not more responsible for allocating or deallocating the array. In other words, it does not own it anymore.

In your case, you can use the function return to pass the amount of slots used in this array and, on error, just a negative number.

In this way, your program can be something like that:

```
int get_factors(int number, int number[], size_t length)
{
    int x;
    int z;
    int y = 0;

    if ( number > length ) return -1; 

    for(x=1; x <= number; ++x)
    {
         if (number%x == 0)
         {
              arr[y] = x;
              y++;
         }
     }
     return y;
}
```

and at call site:

```
int main(void) {
   int num[MAX_SIZE];
   int temp;
   int z = 0;
   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&temp);

   printf("Factors of %d: ", temp);

   int slots = get_factors(temp, num, MAX_SIZE);

   for(z=0; z<=slots; z++) //This is the loop that i need to figure out a 
       printf("%d ", num[z]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, that actually makes much more sense. I'm still trying to learn everything and all the different techniques. I really appreciate the informative answer and help. Thank you.